# image not found error in angular cli

Tags: html, image, html-lists

When i was using angular quickstart then images are able to print on web browser, but now i am using angular cli and images are not able to print.
i am using same tags same code for both to print images. 
i tried my best.
all dependencies are installed.
Whats wrong with this can anybody help me out of this?

angular-cli version is  6.0.5,
$ node -v version is v10.2.0,
$ npm -v version is 6.0.1

In app.component.ts,

```
export class AppComponent  { 
 appList: any[] = [ {
 "ID": "1",
 "url": 'app/images/1.jpg',
 "height": "30",
 "width":"40",
 "align":'left' }];}
```

In app.component.html,

```
<div *ngFor = 'let lst of appList'>
<ul>
   <li>{{lst.ID}}</li>
   <img [src] = 'lst.url' [height] ='lst.height' [width] ='lst.width' [align] = 'lst.align' >
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried testing the image with the string directly?

Comment: <img src='app/images/1.jpg'> I tried this same output is thier. above code is working in angular quickstart, but i want angular 2 cli.

Comment: Have you checked that the path is correct, relative to the app component?

Comment: is their any command to print images?? 1) npm install -g @angular/cli , 2)ng new angularProject , 3) cd angularProject  ,4)added these code blocks, and then 5)ng serve --open. anything else to install ???

Comment: path is also correct "D:\angularProject\src\app\images"

Comment: Shouldn't it be 'images/1.jpg'? If that code is in the app component, then you are already inside the `app` folder.

Comment: images is one of my folder which is based inside app folder. i tried with full path also like, <img src='angularProject/src/app/images/1.jpg'> and like this, <img src='src/app/images/1.jpg'>

Comment: Yes, and since you are in the app component, the relative path would be 'images/1.jpg'.

Comment: hmm, you mean i need to write it like, <img src='images/1.jpg'> i tried this also. Its not worked for me.

Comment: GET http://localhost:4200/images/1.jpg 404 (Not Found)         1.jpg:1

Comment: Have you tried putting an image in the same folder as the component and trying to display it normally with a html img tag?

Comment: GET http://localhost:4200/1.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Comment: its done thanks for support but the solution is like, i need to copy my images inside "assets" folder. Now i am able to see images.